# Which wifi repeater to buy that can be OS X configured?

Tags: wifi, hardware-recommendation

I need to extend my Wi-Fi and would like the type that just plugs into the mains.

I cannot find a repeater or extender that does not use Windows to configure.

Is there a repeater or extender which can be configured with OS X?

Comment: Are you looking for a powerline adapter? I don't think I've ever seen one that required Windows, or any other specific operating system.  They usually set up automatically and don't need to be connected to a computer at all.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Apple's [AirPort Express](http://www.apple.com/airportexpress/) to extend wireless networks. This can be configured from AirPort Utility in OS X.

Comment: In my experience it only really seems to work (for extending, not bridging) with other Apple routers. Just something to think about.

Comment: The AirPort devices can be configured as a bridge, at least it was possible March 2007. That is when I have setup AirPort devices to bridge the network of 5 river ships with an office. I haven't worked with AirPort Express.